# What is the Hausdorff dimension of the set of irrationals on $\mathbb R^1$

Tags: measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

I am sorry if this is a dump question but I can't find any reference for this. What is the Hausdorff dimension of the set of irrationals on $\mathbb R^1$?

I speculate this is $1$ but don't know how to prove it rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure for any $d > 1$ is nonatomic, so any countable set has $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $0$.  In particular the rationals have $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $0$, and the irrationals
have infinite $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.  On the other hand the $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of $\mathbb R$ is $0$ for $d > 1$.  So the irrationals have Hausdorff dimension $1$.